# sets in python problem

Tags: python

I want to use sets as data structure. how should i make it possible?
what are the commands I need?

Like closedset = set()

is this ok?

And in a set, if i want to get some value out, what is the command for that one?

Comment: Have you considered to read the [ **documentation** ](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)? It is very important that you learn to work with the Python documentation, it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. To create an empty set, write `foo = set()`. To retrieve values, you can iterate over the set:

```
for val in someset:
    print val
```

You can also write `val in someset` to check if an item is in a set.

Be sure to read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) for how to do set operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can say`mySet = set(),` which will give you a blank set to work with.  Additionally, one method I found useful usually is converting from tuples/lists to sets, which you can do by saying `mySet = set([1,2,3,4,5])`.

What do you mean you'd like to get some value out?  As in whether or not an item is a member of the set?  For determining membership, you can use the usual python idiom of `1 in mySet` to determine whether 1 is in the set or not.

And yes, the docs are right [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)